# Is there a way for mongodb clients to connect to mongodb server (SSL/TLS enabled) without client certificates?

Tags: mongodb, security, ssl, tls-1.2

I am trying to setup a MongoDB with SSL/TLS enabled. I'm just wondering is there a way for clients to connect to my mongodb server without having a client certificate that would not compromise the security? (not considering --sslAllowInvalidCertificates or --tlsInsecure=true)

Just like how mongodb atlas is doing it.

Comment: SCRAM or Kerberos maybe? https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set [`net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: true`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.tls.allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates)

Of course, [`net.tls.mode`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/configuration-options/#mongodb-setting-net.tls.mode) must not set to `requireTLS`, use `preferTLS` or `allowTLS`

Encryption of connection is provided by server certificate, the client certificate has effect on that. Also note, that the *Subject Alternative Name* (SAN) of client certificates are not checked when a connection is established. Thus in my opinion, a client certificate gives only minor security improvements, unless it is used for [client authentication](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/configure-x509-client-authentication/).